# como restaurar Banco de Dados MySQL

Tags: mysqldump

Tentei fazer o seguinte para restaurar o banco de dados:

```
root@m9r9w9gae3 [/bkp/var/lib/mysql]# mysqldump -u root -p nomedobd > /home/nmedobd.sql
```

ou:

```
root@m9r9w9gae3 [/bkp/var/lib/mysql/nomedobd]# mysqldump -u root -p cfellini_wp > /home/nomedobd.sql
```

Apareceu o seguinte erro:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1017: 
 Can’t find file: ‘./nomedobd/cf_commentmeta.frm’ (errno: 13) when using LOCK TABLES
```

Comment: O que apresentou não é “restaurar”, é “exportar”.  Quanto ao erro 1017, geralmente um `check table` e `repair table` pode resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer RESTAURAR um arquivo de backup existente, pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
#mysql -u root -p nomedobd < /home/nmedobd.sql
```

Se você quer GERAR um arquivo de backup, pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
#mysqldump  -u root -p nomedobd > /home/nmedobd.sql
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Qualquer dúvida, deixa um comentário.